# How to add checkboxes in multiple columns in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, checkbox, clistctrl, visual-c++-2005

I am new to the Visual C++, I am using Visual C++ 2005, I want to show  some records in report where I am using `ListControl`. My single entry of records contains two boolean fields so that each row in the `ListControl` are to be represented with the Check boxes. In short there will be two checkboxes in each row. I used the `ListControl` but I found that there comes only one checkbox for each entry. So can anybody please explain how I can add multiple columns of checkboxes in `ListControl`, also what other classes I can use for doing same thing in visual C++. I implemented `InitDialog` as:

```
BOOL MyRecords::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    m_listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1,"First-Bool");
    m_listCtrl.SetColumnWidth(0, 70);

    UInt16 i = 0;
    CString pcid;

    for ( ; i <= 503; i++) {
        pcid.Format(_T("%d"), i);
        m_listCtrl.InsertItem(i, pcid);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's best to use `return TRUE;` when using `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CListCtrl` class with report view will allow you to add checkboxes only in the **first column**. To add checkboxes in the multiple columns you have to **derive** the CListCtrl of your own and you have do it by your own. Here are the few examples which may help you:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1796/XListCtrl-A-custom-draw-list-control-with-subitem
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8112/CQuickList