# MFC Custom Control draw

Tags: c++, mfc

I have some question.
I made custom controller inner radio button.
but that is not clear draw every time ( blink or overlapped ).

so, question is this
how are you draw customctrl inner controller?
draw use CDC? or inner controller redraw()? ( i'm used redraw() )

second is listctrl frequently covered inner radio button.
how can i draw inner radio button above listctrl every time.

here is my code :
vfcxxx : xxx same

```
void CCheckListCtrl::DrawItem(_In_ LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    int cnt = lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
    static int rownumber = 0;

    VfcLong tmpnum = -1;
    LONG prev_left = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.left;

    LV_COLUMN column_data;
    memset(&column_data, 0, sizeof(LV_COLUMN));
    column_data.mask = LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_FMT;

    for(int column_index = 0; GetColumn(column_index, &column_data); column_index++)
    {
        RECT tempRC;
        {
            tempRC.top  = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.top;
            tempRC.bottom = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.bottom;
            tempRC.left  = (prev_left);
            tempRC.right = (prev_left += column_data.cx);
        }

        if (column_index > 1) break;

        LV_ITEM tempLI;
        wchar_t buffer[256];
        {
            tempLI.mask   = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM;
            tempLI.iItem  = lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
            tempLI.iSubItem  = column_index;
            tempLI.pszText  = buffer;
            tempLI.cchTextMax = sizeof(buffer);
            VERIFY(GetItem(&tempLI));
        }

        CString tmpChk = buffer;
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);

        if( (tmpnum = isInsert(defaultGroup, cnt)) != -1)
        {
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
        else if( (tmpnum = isInsert(radioGroup, cnt)) != -1)
        {
            radioCell cell = radioGroup[tmpnum];
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(cell.color[0], cell.color[1], cell.color[2]));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(125, 125, 125));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
        else 
        {
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
    }
    setVisibleRowNumber();
    setVisibleAttrRadioButton(prev_left - column_data.cx/2);
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::setVisibleRowNumber()
{
    visibleMinRow = GetScrollPos(SB_VERT);
    visibleMaxRow = visibleMinRow + 12;
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::setVisibleAttrRadioButton(VfcLong left)
{
    VfcLong row;
    radioCell cell;
    for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        row = radioGroup[i].row;
        cell = radioGroup[i];

        if( row >= visibleMinRow && row <= visibleMaxRow)
        {
            cell.btn->SetWindowPos(NULL, left - 6, (row - visibleMinRow + 1) * 19 + 4, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
            cell.btn->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            cell.btn->RedrawWindow();
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btn->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892712/mfc-blink-control-custom-checklistctrl) multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use controls inside a control such. You will never reduce all flickering that is caused by the overlapping of windows.

Draw the button yourself. Also CListCtrl has its own check box style.
Here is [one sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13586/Using-Check-Box-in-List-Control).

And even adding multiple checkboxes to a CListCtrl has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309526/how-to-add-checkboxes-in-multiple-columns-in-vc).